# Motion planning collision checking on Gazebo virtual worlds

Tags: ros, gazebo, octomap, collision-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I will create a virtual building in Gazebo with the [building editor](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=building_editor&cat=build_world). Then, I want to do motion planning in that building. In the past, I was carrying out a mapping step in which I was teleoperating the robot and building an octomap from the sensor data. Then I used the octomap for collision checking.

Now, I would like to directly use the environment saved for collision checking or to automatically convert it into an octomap (or just a 3D occupancy grid), so I do not need to manually sense the map. Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211838/motion-planning-collision-checking-on-gazebo-virtual-worlds/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-26**:
No suggestions? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this gazebo plugin that converts to octomap from a mesh:
https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator/blob/master/rotors_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_octomap_plugin.cpp

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3